# Selecting a parent class from a child class when there are multiple div's of same parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are four parent div's with same class and all of them have a child with class 'child'. Now the question is, Let's say I click on the First parent div's Child div(First Child) and I want to have some effect on it's parent i.e 'First Parent' to be effected only. Due to being similar class' all parent div's will be effected.
Here's the HTML

```
<div class="parent"> //First Parent
   <div class="child"></div> //First Child
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the JQuery

```
$('.child').on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent('.parent').css({
      'display':'none';
   });
});
```

Clicking on child element will effect all parent div's with class "parent". Either I can give them all separate classes then write onClick() method for all of them but that is not a proper solution.

Comment: Using the code in your example only the parent of the clicked element will be affected. `.parent('.parent')` will return the first parent with that class. Take a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) !

Comment: The parent() is working and the closest() as well, but all the parent div's have same class and I'm adding onClick to child element's with class 'child'. The desired functionality still won't be achieved.

Comment: Inside the onClick callback `this` refers to the clicked element not to all `.child` elements which means that `.parent(".parent")` will return only the parent of the clicked element.

Comment: Yes you're right, but there's also one thing to notice is that every child div has .child class so this onClick() will be applied on every child div.

Comment: Even if it is applied to multiple elements, `this` will still refer to the clicked one. `$(this) != $(".child")`, `$(this) == ClickedElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use closest('.class')

```
$('.child').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.parent').css('display':'none');
});
```

**I Updated my answer !**

Comment: I've tried this as well but it will still effect all parent div's.

Comment: +1 to this one, as it is more versatile than the other anser. Incase the "child" div somewhere down the road becomes a child of another container div between the parent element and itself

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

if you want to hide the parent of the clicked div

Comment: It will still effect all parent div's.

Comment: @PraveenBisht It will not effect all the parent div. Here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/2ozjduda/

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.child').on('click',function(){
       $(this).closest('.parent').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

OR

```
$('.child').on('click',function(){
$(this).parent('.parent').eq(0).css('display','none');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t9wxbLs8/

Comment: @parveen Bisht try this out i hope it helped.

Comment: Good one, I'll check my code again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if it helped i need an upvote to reinstate my question asking ability, at the moment i am not able to ask questions. :\

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

alterate your JS as follow:

```
$('.child').on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().css({
      'display':'none'
   });
});
```

For me, on click of a div, it hides its parent. Not others.
By the way, you had a ";" after 'none' which is invalid as this is a object, and accepts only either nothing or a comma.

see https://jsfiddle.net/n66sdgdz/

Comment: lol sorry about that but that is not the problem. Since the selected class is '.child' that is the class for every child, so all of the parent '.parent' div's will be effected as well on click.

Comment: click the jsfiddle you will see it is not affecting others.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I may have an issue in my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct and a good practice, I don't see what the issue here is.

The only change you could do `$(this).parent('.parent').hide();` instead of using the jQuery css method.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">first</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">second</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">third</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">fourth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.child').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('.parent').css({
      'display':'none'
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"> //First Parent
   <div class="child">div 1</div> //First Child
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">div 3</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">div 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so lots of answers here with "try this" or other examples.

First off, your code actually works, as you can see here:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3bo67e6/1/)

However, there was one error in you code. This being the `;` at the end of your `'display':'none';`

There should be no `;` inside a javascript object.

Comment: I made that error in this question only, but thanks for your help I may have some issues in the CSS.